# How to add a shader to a fixed-pipeline OpenGL app

Tags: macos, opengl, fragment-shader

I am updating an existing app for Mac OS that is based on the older fixed-pipeline OpenGL. (OpenGL 2, I guess it is.) It uses an NSOpenGLView and an ortho projection to create animated kaleidoscopes, with either still images or input from a connected video camera.

It was written before HD cameras were available (or at least readily so.) It's written to expect YCBCR_422 video frames from Quicktime (k422YpCbCr8CodecType) and passes the frames to OpenGL as GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE to map them to a texture.

My company decided it was time to update the app to support the new crop of HD cameras, and I am not sure how to proceed.

I have a decent amount of OpenGL experience, but my knowledge is spotty and has gaps in it.

I'm using the delegate method captureOutput:didOutputVideoFrame:withSampleBuffer:fromConnection to receive frames from the camera via a QTCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput

I have a Logitech c615 for testing, and the buffers I'm getting are reported as being in 32 bit RGBA (GL_RGBA8) format. I believe it's actually in ARGB format.

However, according to the docs on glTexImage2D, the only supported input pixel formats are GL_COLOR_INDEX, GL_RED, GL_GREEN, GL_BLUE, GL_ALPHA, GL_RGB, GL_BGR GL_RGBA, GL_BGRA,  GL_LUMINANCE, or GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA.

I would like to add a fragment shader that would swizzle my texture data into RGBA format when I map my texture into my output mesh.

Since writing this app I've learned the basics of shaders from writing iOS apps for OpenGL ES 2, which does not support fixed pipeline OpenGL at all.

I really don't want to rewrite the app to be fully shader based if I can help it. I'd like to implement an optional fragment shader that I can use to swizzle my pixel data for video sources when I need it, but continue to use the fixed pipeline for managing my projection matrix and model view matrix.

How do you go about adding a shader to the (otherwise fixed) rendering pipeline?

Comment: After doing some more digging, I found that the actual memory of the pixels is stored in the kCVPixelFormatOpenGLFormat key of the pixel format dictionary I get from CVPixelFormatDescriptionCreateWithPixelFormatType, and the data is in GL_BGRA, which IS supported by glTexImage2D. Thus I don't need to resort to swizzling in this case. I'm still interested in how to add a shader to my fixed-pipeline OpenGL code however.

Comment: Also, you do not need a `GL_ARGB` *per-se*. You can use `GL_BGRA` and then when you do pixel transfer (e.g. `glTexImage2D (...)`) use a `GL_..._REV` data type to reverse order of the components. Understanding this alone might save you a lot of pain in the long-run, because this is effectively how you handle ARGB and ABGR pixel formats. They are not native, but you can have GL flip the component order during pixel transfer (in/out) and make them a complete non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to ask this, but what exactly is your problem now? It is not that difficult to attach shaders to the fixed function pipeline; all you need is to reimplement that tiny bit of functionality that vertex and fragment shaders are replacing. You can use built-in GLSL variables like gl_ModelViewMatrix or such to use values that have been setup by your legacy OpenGL code; you can find some of them here: http://www.hamed3d.org/Res/GLSL_Reference/0321552628_AppI.pdf